# Taxonomy Term URL based on Panel Contextual filter path

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I run a Drupal 7 website that is a multiple resort guide.

I have set up a panel page based on 2 contextual filters.

**www.domain.com/resort/%1/things-to-do/%2**

**%1** = Taxonomy Term **[Vocabulary:Resort]** (*term names: Magaluf, Malia, Zante, Ibiza etc)*

**%2** = Taxonomy Term **[Vocabulary:Attraction_Categories]** *(term names: Boat Parties, Stag Parties)*

I have a node [nod:type:Attraction]. When creating a new 'Attraction' you tag this node with the corresponding tags (Resort/Attraction Category).

For eg;

domain.com/resorts/**ibiza**/things-to-do/**boat-parties**/[node:type:Attraction]
domain.com/resorts/**malia**/things-to-do/**stag-parties**/[node:type:Attraction]
domain.com/resorts/**magaluf**/things-to-do/**beach-parties**/[node:type:Attraction]

The panel display's all attraction nodes in **teaser displays** based on the contextual filter from the URL.

For eg: domain.com/resorts/**magaluf**/things-to-do/**beach-parties**/ will display all the [node:type:attraction]'s of all the **beach-parties** in **magaluf**

---

**What I am trying to do:**

I would like to create a view on the parent page of the attraction categories panel page for each particular resort (eg Ibiza, domain.com/resorts/ibiza/things-to-do)

This view will then display links of all the terms of the **vocabulary:attraction-categories.** Each taxonomy term will link from that specific resort it is displayed in.

For example, selecting the term **Beach Parties** on page www.domain.com/resorts/**zante**/things-to-do would take you to domain.com/resorts/**zante**/things-to-do/**beach-parties**

I have been playing around with a view to display all taxonomy terms of the vocabulary - Attraction Categories then re-writing the output of the taxonomy temr URL to **resorts/%1/things-to-do/[term:name]** but no luck. :-(

Please help as I am now running out of ideas.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I will pay for help!!